# SOLR add new data to existing index

Tags: php, search, solr, indexing

I am creating index with some data from database. Following is the code:

```
       // Load the documents into the index
        try {
            // $documents holds all the documents
            $solr->addDocuments($documents);     
            $solr->commit();
            $solr->optimize();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
```

It is creating index properly. Now, if I want to add some extra data to it, shall I follow the same process with those extra data or there is any other procedure to update solr index?

If I follow the same process, will it overwrite the existing index or it will just update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene's indexing process consists of inserts and deletes. Solr, through schema design and enforcement, provides update-like functionality through a message handler by combining a delete/insert sequence inside one method call.

When your schema design includes a uniqueKey, posting updates to Solr will automatically update the record in your index.

Comment: Yes, my schema does include a unique key. So, you are saying, I can continue using the same process of adding documents.

Comment: @Swar - yes, you can continue with your indexing process as-is.